# Playwright - test runs infinite if assertion fails

Tags: playwright, playwright-test, playwright-typescript

I've encountered a problem with one of the workspaces - Playwright & Visual Studio code.

When Playwright starts a test/process and the test fails - the process is not cancelled.

At the same time, I've opened the same project on the second computer I use. It works fine. After an assertion failure, the test fails and the report opens.

I also have problems on the 1st workstation with positive output - because even if the test passes, the execution time is very long compared to the other workstation.

There are the screenshots:
[playwright trace viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02A96.png)
[running test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynwUE.png)

Expected:

- Test process should be processed correctly on failure. Return failure information.
- Report should open after failing
- Reduction in execution time (?) The difference between workspaces is now (33s to 5 seconds)

I've tried multiple times reinstalling the VS code with node and playwright. I've deleted the app data files... and nothing helps at all

I'm getting the same result on a freshly opened project, so it's probably not something to do with my code.

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] of your code and package.json? Thanks.

Comment: When you uninstall are you also deleting all the files manually in: C:\Users\jsmith\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code ?
Those files don't get deleted during the uninstall process.

Comment: I am having the same issue, what version of Playwright, node, npm are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with my tests going into infinite retry and/or rerunning continuously till I forcefully stop it. This started when I upgraded Playwright to the latest `1.42.0` version. It also exists in the `1.42.1` version. To solve this I had to downgrade to version `1.41.2`

`"@playwright/test": "^1.41.2",`

I am unsure what caused this but yeah, downgrading makes it work again.